# Password manager for Linux with just working in-browser autotype

Tags: linux, ubuntu, password-manager

I'm looking for a good password manager for Linux. Currently I use KeePass2, but it is known to be developed primarily for Windows and has many issues running on Mono. For example, autotype is not working for me. (My OS is Ubuntu 13.04.)

My requrements:

- It should be very secure, of course
- As already mentioned, it needs to have a just-working in-browser autotype
- The data file location should be configurable - I want to back it up using Dropbox
- It should have a password generation feature
- Entries should be able to be categorized into folders, as in KeePass

Comment: See also [Password manager for Linux and Android](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1311)

Comment: Folks, thanks for all the answers here, but please **do not use comments** to answer questions as a means of making recommendations without sufficient detail. While your comments seem well-meaning, if you can flesh it out further so it can be vetted by the community, please feel free to post it as a proper 'answer' below. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**[KeePassX](http://www.keepassx.org/)** might be of special interest to you, if the Mono trouble was the only thing bothering you. It's a native port of *KeePass* to Linux and MacOS X and, as you're running Ubuntu, even contained in the official (Ubuntu) repositories, so a simple

```
sudo apt-get install keepassx
```

will put it on your machine (and a corresponding start-icon into *Accessories → KeePassX*).

**So how does it match your requirements?**

- *it should be very secure:* Yes, it is. You can chose between either the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) or the Twofish algorithm
- *working in-browser autotype:* It offers a feature called "AutoFill"
- *configurable location of the data file:* You have only one? You can have many :)
- *password generation:* Yes, with several options (see screenshot below)
- *ability to categorize passwords into folders:* Yes, we (s)can! See screenshot below.

[image: Main Window] [image: Password Generator]
<sup>Main window and password generator (click images for larger variants)</sup>

**Additional benefits** are the platform independency (you can even use your current database from *KeePass* with it, and can use the very same on Android, or wherever), a nice interface, user-defined symbols for groups and entries are possible (to make the items easier to identify), a quality indicator for chosen passwords; a search function, ...

**Possible draw-backs** might include its rigid structures for the records: it's clearly written with website logins in mind (URL, login, password, comments). I find it hard to use it for e.g. credit card or bank account information. Also, it only supports the KeePass 1.x (`.kbd`) database format (a good thing when using the Android App "in sync", as that also is restricted to v1.x databases), not the newer v2.x `.kbdx` format.

Also note note that the current stable version (0.4.3) was [published 4 years ago](http://www.keepassx.org/changelog/) and is [no langer maintained](http://www.keepassx.org/bug-reports/). While KeePassX 2 seems to be actively developed, but it’s currently an alpha version. <sup>(thanks to [unor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/60/unor) for pointing this out)</sup>

**P.S.:** Definitly see [Caleb's answer on my question here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1237/185#1311) for more details and background on KeePassX and its latest versions!

Comment: Please note that the current stable version (0.4.3) was [published 4 years ago](http://www.keepassx.org/changelog/) and is [no langer maintained](http://www.keepassx.org/bug-reports/). KeePassX 2 seems to be actively developed, but it’s currently an alpha version.

Comment: @unor et all: my answer on [Password manager for Linux and Android](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1311) has some more background and detailed status of this software.

Answer (score 7):

If you don’t mind using a cloud based password manager [LastPass](https://lastpass.com) is just awesome.

[image: Lastpass vault page]

LastPass is cross platform and cross browser and cross mobile platform application which is free but offer also a premium version for 1$ monthly and additional features.

As requested:

- **It's secure -** uses AES 256-bit encryption.
- **Auto login -** After saving a website's username and password, LastPass will autofill the login when you return to that site.
- **Passwords location -** passwords can be exportes in CVS LastPass or encrypted LastPass format, it can even export it to Firefox.
- **Password generation feature** - the LastPass password generator appears when you're creating an account or updating an existing one.
- **Categorized into folders -**  all your accounts and passwords in one easy-to-use "vault", where you can edit, delete, and organize
  your stored data.

For full list of all features visit [here](https://lastpass.com/features_free.php)

Answer (score 0):

[Figaro's Password Manager 2](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/fpm2/) does everything that you require. I am not 100% sure about the organization into folders however. It does allow you to put them into categories.

> Figaro's Password Manager 2 (FPM2) is a program that allows you to securely store the passwords. Passwords are encrypted with the AES-256 algorithm.
>
> If the password is for a web site, FPM2 can keep track of the URLs of your login screens and can automatically launch your browser. In this capacity, FPM2 acts as a kind of bookmark manager. You can teach FPM2 to launch other applications, and optionally pass hostnames, usernames or passwords to the command line.
>
> FPM2 also has a password generator that can choose passwords for you. It allows you to determine how long the password should be, and what types of characters (lower case, upper case, numbers and symbols) should be used. You can even have it avoid ambiguous characters such as a capital O or the number zero.

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you use this tool? Could you tell us something about it? Is it easy to use? Has it some caveats? Your personal experience is?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Keepass together with [KeeFox](http://keefox.org/) works just fine, and you have some additional features such as password generation saving login data from within Firefox, including fields that are more than just username+password.

Answer (score 0):

[Enpass](https://www.enpass.io/apps/linux/) is the best, most platform-versatile password manager I have found.

- Has Windows, Mac, Chromebook, Android, iOS versions, **Linux (including Ubuntu)**, and Blackberry versions
- Autosaves / syncs
- Optional autostart, without asking for password immediately
- Passwords are stored locally, with **optional sync to personal cloud storage** accounts (i.e. Google Drive, Dropbox, Box)
- **Can be categorized with folders**
- Database is encrypted with AES 256 and a master password
- Passwords can be mass exported
- Has community forum for suggestions, etc.
- Actively maintained
- Password generation (with recipe)
- **Supports browser autofill**
- Is **FREE** for desktop versions

And a bonus, which is very important to me, it is user-friendly, and has a gorgeous interface. It can store anything from standard passwords and accounts, to hunting licenses and lens prescriptions.