# Cross OS Digital vault application

Tags: windows, android, cross-platform

I would like to store securely :

> bank accounts
>   credit cards
>   notes
>   documents

I would like the app to be :

> `protected` by password or pin code
>   able to work `offline`
>   able to `sync` the data across `windows` and `android`
>   free or having a small price

I am already using `LastPass` as my password manager, but having the mobile version implies a year fee.
I have tried `Everlast`, but for having all this I will also have to have a yearly paid version.

Is there a app that has all / some the features described above ?
Thanks

Comment: If it weren's also for documents, I'd say one of the [Password Safes](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_password) for Android (and have *KeePass* in mind, which is multi-platform – see [Password manager for Linux and Android](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1237/185)).

Comment: I tried `KeePass` and `Keepass2Android` with the `kdbx file` shared on `Google Drive` and I'am realy impressed. Thanks for the advice @Izzy

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, lonut! Do you think this deserves a separate answer – or should we rather close your question as duplicate to the one I've linked to in my previous comment?

Comment: Yes, it should be closed as a duplicate. The one you linked in your previous comment did not showed in my search because was a linux-android solution and not a windows-android one. Once again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Anytime – glad we've found a solution you're happy with!