# Password manager for the Linux command line

Tags: linux, open-source, command-line, password-manager

I'm looking for a password manager for the Linux (Debian/Ubuntu) **command line** to be used by a department of developers.

We are currently using [pwman3](https://github.com/pwman3/pwman3) and content with it but want to migrate to a program that does not change its database format so often in incompatible ways.

#### What I need:

- must be available as a Linux (Ubuntu LTS, Debian) command line application
- secure storage (i.e. good encryption)
- centralized storage possible (an NFS share or a Git repo would be good enough), no cloud please
- data file location should be configurable
- free/open source software

#### Preferred options (not mandatory)

- nice [GUI](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1237/1423)
- is contained in Ubuntu repositories (PPA is fine, a `.deb` would do, no problems if it comes as `.jar` or ready-to-go `.tar.gz` however, or source if not too many dependencies (we feel fit enough to `configure && make && check-install` ;))

#### Candidates tried, but failed:

- [pwman3](https://github.com/pwman3/pwman3): We use it now with a central DB file (shared via NFS), but the DB format was changed in an incompatible way between Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.10, so that the 14.04 clients can not read the DB stored by 15.10.
- [pwsafe](https://github.com/nsd20463/pwsafe): A command line client for [Password Safe](https://pwsafe.org/index.shtml) files, but sadly it has not been updated since 2005.

Comment: Is `vi` OK? If not, what features do you need?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: For example encrypted storage of passwords. I'm not sure vi can do that. :-) We're happy with pwman3, but the incompatible database formats (e.g. between Ubuntu 14.04, 15.10 and 16.04) are a no-go.

Comment: There are so many password management tools with very different features, so we can't guess what your expectations are. Please write the list of requirements, thanks :-) Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information and edit your question. Cheers!

Comment: For the very same issue (collection of username/password) we've used a plain text file with two GPG scripts: 1 script to only "view" and 1 to edit (add/change entries). The file would be encrypted using the public keys of *all* participants, so each dev can decrypt it with his/her private key. Easy approach, no permanently changing database formats :)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: Better? :-)

Comment: @Izzy: Sounds like a nice solution. Could you make the scripts available somewhere?

Comment: Afraid not. That was a customer I worked for several years ago, and I didn't create the scripts. But with the concept in mind, it shouldn't be too complicated to create them (not that I volunteer ;) Quick hint: [Encrypting and decrypting documents - GnuPG](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x110.html) and on our sister site [Encryption with multiple different keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/597188/2533433)

Comment: Great question now!

Comment: Does LastPass meat your openness requirement? The [CLI client](https://github.com/lastpass/lastpass-cli) is open source (indeed, it's even [packaged in Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=lastpass-cli)), but the service it uses is not.

Comment: @derobert: Can I install the server on-premise?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Not so far as I know. But that wasn't one of your requirements (though maybe it should be).

Comment: @derobert: Question is updated: "No cloud please"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Kruptos

I was similarly dissatisfied with most password managers and wanted a minimalist/command-line alternative, so I created [Kruptos](https://gist.github.com/NonlinearFruit/7b6f72f97f0d70086f3f229fbf23850f). Kruptos simply encrypts and decrypts the `~/.kruptos/` directory. This provides several benefits:

- **Non-intrusive**: store sensitive info the way you want
- **Flexible lookup**: search/modify passwords with command line tools
- **Modifiable**: the source code is simple and easily changed
- **Distributable**: compresses to a tarball when encrypted

### Usage

Kruptos has 3 pieces of functionality:

- **Initialize**: create `~/.kruptos/` and `~/.kruptos/.phrazein` with default master password `pswd`

  - The first line of `.phrazein` is the master password
- **Encrypt**: compress, encrypt and then remove `~/.kruptos/` which creates the tarball
- **Decrypt**: decrypt, decompress and then remove `.kruptos.tar.gz.aes` which creates the directory

```
+===============+===========+
| Functionality | Command   |
+===============+===========+
| Initialize    | kruptos i |
+---------------+-----------+
| Encrypt       | kruptos e |
+---------------+-----------+
| Decrypt       | kruptos   |
+===============+===========+
```

### Code

```
function kruptos
{
    if [[ $# -eq 1 ]]; then
        DOWHAT="$1"
    else
        DOWHAT="d"
    fi
    if [[ $DOWHAT == "d" ]]; then
        #Decrypt
        pushd . &>/dev/null
        cd ~/
        openssl aes-256-cbc -d  -in .kruptos.tar.gz.aes | tar -xz -f - --strip-components=2 && rm ~/.kruptos.tar.gz.aes
        popd &>/dev/null
    elif [[ $DOWHAT == "e" ]]; then
        #Encrypt
        tar -zcf - ~/.kruptos | openssl aes-256-cbc -out ~/.kruptos.tar.gz.aes -kfile ~/.kruptos/.phrazein && rm -r ~/.kruptos
    elif [[ $DOWHAT == "i" ]]; then
        #Initialize
        mkdir ~/.kruptos
        echo pswd > ~/.kruptos/.phrazein
    else
        echo "$DOWHAT is not an acceptable flag"
    fi
}
```

---

### Origins

**Kruptos**

[image: Kruptos origins]

**Phrazein**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## KeePass

The KeePass is available under http://keepass.info/ .
There is a command line client http://kpcli.sourceforge.net/ or a Java API so you can roll your own.

I am using it for years now and it works well on Mac, Win, and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

## Passme

I made a password manager for the command line. Just install it with:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip  
sudo pip3 install passme
```

It stores the information of "seed for password" in a text file, and you can manage it with git. It creates your password from "seed for password" and a master password you remember. It can also create a html file to be used from your mobile device.

For what you need:

- It is available from the Linux command line.
- Only the "seed for password" is stored, which does not reveal your password unless your master password is known.
- It uses only a single text file, which is easily manageable with git repo.
- Data file location is configurable.
- MIT license

For more information:

- Documentation: https://github.com/sekika/passme/blob/master/doc/README.rst
- Tutorial movie: https://youtu.be/6DXPhyYhYsE