# Password manager for Android, Linux, and Windows

Tags: windows, android, linux, open-source, password-manager

I am looking for password manager with following features:

- has Linux, Windows and Android versions (different programs capable of using the same database are also OK)
- does not require additional manual saving after new password was added (it eliminates KeePass 2)
- it is possible to add it to autostart, without asking for password immediately after start (it eliminates KeePass 2)
- passwords are not leaving computer (no kind of any "cloud synchronization", also for encrypted passwords)
- password database is encrypted until user gives master password
- ability to export all data from program
- open source
- actively maintained software
- ability to generate random password

Strongly preferable:

- there was an independent security audit
- recommended by security experts
- gratis
- autotype available

Comment: How would it go from linux, windows to android if there's no cloud sync?

Comment: @Raystafarian As I use primarily Linux (and it may be assumed that all passwords are added there) it would be quite easy to schedule local replication of database file (in case of Linux -> Windows it would be trivial as Windows resides on a different partition of the same computer).

Comment: Related: [Password manager for Linux and Android](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1237/185) (has at least one solution that matches here). As for "no cloud sync", @Raystafarian: Ever heard that you can sync using your own resources? I'm doing that regularly in my home WiFi, using my PC as "local cloud" :) Check *FolderSync* for that :)

Comment: @Izzy KeePassX also fails "does not require additional manual saving after new password was added".

Comment: https://www.roboform.com/

Comment: @mle Fails multiple requirements, starting from requirement that password are not leaving also my computer, also in encrypted form.

Comment: @mle Also, their website start with a lie. Password manager is NOT an unique product in 2017. It is not encouraging me to believe that they are competent or trustworthy.

Comment: @mle Also, apparently on 2017 they still have fixed-width unscrollable pages like https://www.roboform.com/business/how-it-works that are unusable on mobile.

Answer (score 4):

[Enpass](https://enpass.io) is the closes thing I have found to your requirements.  It fails your requirements on open-source only.

- Has Windows, Mac, Chromebook, Android, iOS versions, and Blackberry versions
- Autosaves / syncs
- Optional autostart, without asking for password immediately
- Passwords are stored locally, with optional sync to personal cloud storage accounts (i.e. Google Drive, Dropbox, Box)
- Database is encrypted with master password
- Passwords can be mass exported
- **NOT** Open source, but has community forum for suggestions, etc.
- Actively maintained
- Password generation (with recipe)
- Supports browser autofill

And a bonus, which is very important to me, it is ***user-friendly***, and has a gorgeous interface.  It can store anything from standard passwords and accounts, to hunting licenses and lens prescriptions.