# Secure, Remotely Accessible, Windows Password Manager

Tags: windows, android, password-manager, remote-access

I am looking for a password manager to keep track of the plethora of work and personal passwords I have.

Requirements:

1. Windows Compatible (7)
2. Remotely accessible from my android device (HTC1)
3. Very Secure.  I want to use it for Banking and my Work System passwords (I don't know much about security if anyone can elaborate/suggest an expected standard for me)
4. Cost is relevant, <100 USD, preferably one time but annually would be fine as well.  Cost is secondary to security and functionality, so do not hold back a recommendation for cost concerns.

Comment: You might wish to take a look at [Password manager for Linux with just working in-browser autotype](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/541/185) and [Password manager for Linux and Android](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1237/185). Not 100% matching, but solutions for Windows/Android are mentioned as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I'll recommend [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/). It meets all of your needs:

- *Windows Compatible (7):* Yes. Cross-platform (Windows, Mac & Linux) *and* cross-browser compatible (all 5 common browsers)!
- *Remotely accessible from my android device (HTC1):* **Premium** version only AFAIK (haven't used it on any remote devices). (there are apps for all the major smart phone OSes)
- *Very Secure. I want to use it for Banking and my Work System passwords (I don't know much about security if anyone can elaborate/suggest an expected standard for me):* Lastpass is very secure; of course generally it is only as secure as your master password. However you can enable multi-factor authentication (might need premium I can't remember - since I don't have cell signal usually I haven't bothered to set that up for anything despite the benefits).
- *Cost is relevant, <100 USD, preferably one time but annually would be fine as well. Cost is secondary to security and functionality, so do not hold back a recommendation for cost concerns.* Free version available. Premium version is well within your price range - $12/year.

Lastpass is also more than just a password app; you can securely (ie encryptedly) store important documents and notes and credit card/address details as well.

Comment: Do you know if you can set up multiple users with a single premium licence?  I do like the answer but I was sorta hoping to get more than one.  Ill accept if I dont see anything in a few more days.

Comment: I'm not sure. (don't have it installed right now - I strongly recommend password apps but I don't generally use them; tried it out quite a while ago but I'm bad, but I can remember my passwords pretty well.)

Comment: I suppose at 12 bucks a month I can always splurge on two accounts if need be. :)

Comment: true. also $12/ **year** so even easier.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [KeePass](http://keepass.info/). (Preferably KeePass 2)

- free
- open source (contrary to **LastPass** which has propriterary code)
- multiplatform (check [downloads](http://keepass.info/download.html) section to see unofficial ports to various platforms. [In another answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1311/2336) can be found some additional info on Linux and Android ports.)
- it can store any type of sensitive information including files (private keys etc.)
- it can synchronize with database on another server, but you have to develop the connection yourself (e.g. set up a VPN)

When keeping passwords **I would NOT go with proprietary software** – I don't trust anyone in this matter.